# latex \def\chapterautorefname{chapter}, position of chapter

Tags: hyperref, autoref

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\chapterautorefname{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\label{1}
This is chapter 1.

Ref \autoref{1} here.

\end{document}
```

This code above give me `chapter 1` when use `\autoref{1}`

In the grammer of my language, it should be `1 chapter`, how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Hungarian, which uses the format you mention.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{chapter}{#2#1.~\chaptername#3}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\label{1}
This is chapter 1.

Ref \cref{1} here.

\end{document}
```

Adapt to your unspecified language.

[image]